# How do you save the response object that I recieve from Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, flask

I'm using a button to call a function that is supposed to fetch data from my backend server hosted in Flask.

The react function passes information to flask and flask returns a JSON response. I have confirmed that Flask receives the necessary information and React receives the response from Flask by looking at the Network Response thing in Google chrome. However, I can't seem to access it.

I have tried to `console.log` it but it does not seem to work. I expected something to print out but nothing does even though the request is being sent.

```js
const fetchDataFromBackend = () => {
  const filters = { age, class, username, };
  fetch('/query', { 
    method: 'POST', 
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(filters)
  }).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
      console.log(response)
      return response.json()
    }
  }).then(data => setTableData(data))
}
```

I know there are similar posts but none of the solutions I have seen have helped. Also, none of the ones I have read mention a button so I am a bit more confused.
I have tried all sorts of things and nothing has really changed.

Comment: Do you mean that `console.log(response)` is never invoked in your code?  When you debug, what does `response` contain?  What does `response.ok` contain?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: I don't think console.log(response) is being invoked as nothing is being printed out in the console. regarding response.ok, im not sure what it exactly contains but i know that the react page is receiving my data from Flask. If you could point me in the right direction to find what response and response.ok contain, I will gladly do it :)

Comment: Well, what happens if you log `response` to the console immediately, instead of inside an `if` block?  Also, are there any errors on the console?

Comment: David when i do response i seem to get the object itself. i was messing around with the code for a little bit and when i do the following line of code, i do see the json i was expecting. I was hoping to also figure out how to save that information to  table data which is a usestate hook.
fetch('/query',{method:'POST',headers:{'Content-Type':'application/json',},body:JSON.stringify(filters)}).then(response  => response.json()).then(data => { console.log(data) })

Comment: So, you no longer want or need to check `response.ok`?  Then what happens if you take that out?  If you're currently able to observe the response data, what stops you from updating state with that data?  It's really not clear what the actual problem is here.

Comment: i do need to check response.ok and i am unsure of how to include that. Also my end goal is to save this data into a useState hook but if i can get the first thing done, that would be nice

Comment: *"i do need to check response.ok"* - And when you do that, what value does it contain?  So far the only "problem" that's been (vaguely) described is that if you wrap code in `if (response.ok)` then that code isn't executed.  So... What is `response.ok`?  What value do you observe it to have?

Comment: response.ok contains true. however when i reverted to the old code, i noticed that I could not access response afterwards in the console. I am a bit new to all this .

Comment: What "old code"?  How are you trying to access `response` in the "old code"?  It sounds like this is very much a moving target, where you're making lots of small changes outside what's presented in the question.  Is the code shown in the question even problematic, or the result of a mistake in debugging some other code?  Now would be a good time for you to create a [mcve] (ideally as a [runnable code snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/328193)) which demonstrates the problem, and indicate specifically what problem you are observing in that example.

Comment: The code I am referring to by "old code" is the one originally listed in the post. I apologize for the confusion and I will clarify now. In the original code, I can access response as an object and response.ok is true. My concern is being able to save and access the information stored in response.json() for later and access it outside of fetch. I want to use the json to construct something else later and store the json in a useState hook. Hopefuly that clarifies everything. I unfortunately cant send running code since this is for work.

Comment: *"response.ok is true"* - Your earlier assertion that *"I don't think console.log(response) is being invoked"* contradicts that, so you're likely making a mistake or false assumption somewhere in your debugging.  If `response.ok` is `true` (or in any way "truthy") then that `if` block would be executing.  Are you looking at a different console somewhere?  When you test the full functionality, is the component's state updated?  (Also, you *can* "send running code", you just may need to replace internal API calls with public ones for testing.)

Comment: Previously, I was looking at something different. This is my first internship and I started 3 days ago so I hope you understand that I am apprehensive to send anything over now especially considering that it is nearing the end of the day. Regarding seeing response.ok as true and now seeing that console.log(response) is being invoked, i am referring to what i can see when I inspect my react web app on google chrome. I am a beginner in all this

Comment: *"now seeing that console.log(response) is being invoked"* - If that was the original problem then is the problem now solved?  *"i am referring to what i can see when I inspect my react web app"* - It's not clear what you mean by that.  If you're expecting that data gets logged to the console, and you're observing that data gets logged to the console, what's the problem?  *"I am apprehensive to send anything over"* - Understandable, but you could (1) reduce the problem to a [mcve] and (2) replicate that example in an entirely new application.  This is a normal part of debugging.

Comment: it technically is solved but if you know anything about being able to access that data later on, it would be much appreciated it. I want to be able to access this data in another component through a useState hook called table data that you may have noticed in the original code. You have been really patient with me and I appreciate it. The tunnel vision hit me lol

Comment: Once the data is in state, you can access it from state.  "In another component" is a bit broad, and there are a variety of ways to share state between components.  You could pass the value as a prop to a child component, you could lift state up to a parent component, you could make use of the `useContext` hook or a state management system like Redux, etc., etc.  At that point you're essentially asking "How do I use React", which isn't really directly answerable.  You are encouraged to walk through some tutorials and continue attempting to write/test/debug your code.